# SQL concatenation inside a vbscript

Tags: sql, vba, string-concatenation

I have a problem with a SQL concatenation used in VB script.

I'm trying to contatenate a variable inside a SQL request but whatever the concatenation method i use, it fails !

Here is my code

```
dim nbr3Eu as integer = 6
dim waa2Eu as string

waa2Eu = "" _
& "SELECT riblib" _
& "      ," & nbr3Eu _
& "  FROM PCH" _
& "  WHERE RibPaysNuf <> 'NufSocPaysMU'" _
& "    AND PchID in " & XPchID _
& "  GROUP BY DevCode"
```

I've tried it with the PLUS sign concatenation but i still have the same result

```
dim nbr3Eu as integer = 6
dim waa2Eu as string

waa2Eu = "" _
+ "SELECT riblib" _
+ "      ," + nbr3Eu _
+ "  FROM PCH" _
+ "  WHERE RibPaysNuf <> 'NufSocPaysMU'" _
+ "    AND PchID in " + XPchID _
+ "  GROUP BY DevCode"
```

Need help, THANKS

Comment: What is failing ? Concatenation or SQL execution ? I want also add that in your first example you make a mix of & and +. Is that normal ? Can you give your error code ?

Comment: the problem is the concatenation inside the SELECT near nbr3Eu, because if i remove that it work. Note that inside the clause WHERE there is a concatenation too but its fine.

Comment: The code accept the concatenation insde the clause WHERE but not inside the SELECT

Comment: I have reduced your code so that your question is more readable. Next time, try to reduce your code so that insignificant part has been removed. My change will be proposed in 10 or 20 minutes by a reviewer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must concatenate String, try replacing `& nbr3Eu` by `& CStr(nbr3Eu)`